# Combine pandas data frames: keep row redundancy while removing column redundancy

Tags: python, pandas

I have three data frames:

```
df1:
col1    col2    col3
name1   human   experID1
name2   mouse   experID2
name3   human   experID3
name4   mouse   experID4
name5   human   experID5

df2:
col1    col2    col4    col6
name1   human   experID1    output1
name2   human   experID2    output2
name3   human   experID3    output3
name10  human   experID10   output4

df3:
col1    col3    col7    col8
name1   happy   human   ref1
name2   sad mouse   ref2
name3   angry   human   ref3
```

I want to combine them:

1. The rows in column 1 must stay the same, i.e. since name1 occurs in each data frame in col1, it should occur three times in the final dataframe.
2. I only want to combine the columns so that: if the column already exists, add the data to that column; else, add a new column.
3. Fill in the missing cells with a '-'

So the output would be:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col6    col7    col8
name1   human   experID1    -   -   -   -
name2   mouse   experID2    -   -   -   -
name3   human   experID3    -   -   -   -
name4   mouse   experID4    -   -   -   -
name5   human   experID5    -   -   -   -
name1   human   -   experID1    output1 -   -
name2   human   -   experID2    output2 -   -
name3   human   -   experID3    output3 -   -
name10  human   -   experID10   output4 -   -
name1   -   happy   -   -   human   ref1
name2   -   sad -   -   mouse   ref2
name3   -   angry   -   -   human   ref3
```

In terms of showing what I tried:
I have three data frames, df1,df2, df3

Was trying to work with merge, concat, append by saying something like:

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame()
list_of_df = [df1,df2,df3]

#method 1
result = pd.concat(list_of_df)

#method 2
for each_df in list_of_dfs:
#this is where it started to go wrong
```

I tried all of the methods on [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) page, but I don't think they do what I want them to (let me know if you want me to add the code from this page here, i just thought since it's wrong, it was neater to point to the link).

I think logically I guess I want to 'append' each data frame to a master data frame one by one, so the rows stay the same. It's just the combining the columns without combining the rows that I don't understand, if someone could show an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems, you want just to append

```
df1.append(df2, sort=False).append(df3, sort=False).fillna('-')
```

Comment: you need sort = False so that a warning does not occur, cocnat is faster

Comment: Can you proof that `concat` is faster? @ansev because it's also a `loopy` implementation

Comment: I have measured it, measure it yourself

Comment: and if you want to add n dataframe you have to use append (n-1) times? That don't make sense....@Erfan

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],sort=False).fillna('-')
```

---

```
     col1   col2      col3       col4     col6   col7  col8
0   name1  human  experID1          -        -      -     -
1   name2  mouse  experID2          -        -      -     -
2   name3  human  experID3          -        -      -     -
3   name4  mouse  experID4          -        -      -     -
4   name5  human  experID5          -        -      -     -
0   name1  human         -   experID1  output1      -     -
1   name2  human         -   experID2  output2      -     -
2   name3  human         -   experID3  output3      -     -
3  name10  human         -  experID10  output4      -     -
0   name1      -     happy          -        -  human  ref1
1   name2      -       sad          -        -  mouse  ref2
2   name3      -     angry          -        -  human  ref3
```